# Postgresql - create anonymous id's

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a list of email addresses I'd like to create a table and assign ids in order to protect the actual user.  What's the easiest way to do this in postgresql?

What I have now:

```
     email          last_contact
bob@xyzcorp.com       20140101
mary@abc.gov          20140606
sara@cde.com          20140708
    ...                  ...
```

I'd like to get something like:

```
     email          anon_id
bob@xyzcorp.com       abc123
mary@abc.gov          abc124
sara@cde.com          abc125
   ...                 ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `uuid-ossp` extension to generate UUIDs like so. (I assumed you want them to be random and not from a `Sequence` which is not alpha-numeric)

```
CREATE EXTENSION "uuid-ossp";
select uuid_generate_v4();
```

Follow this up with a `select into` [query](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-selectinto.html) with the columns that you require for the new table and generate the `UUID` dynamically.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this to create such a result.

```
select email, 
       'abc'||to_char(row_number() over (), 'FM0000') as anon_id
from users;
```

You can either store that in a mapping table or update a new column in your original table.